# CSP report-to directive is not sending report to the endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

I have a CSP (Content Security Policy) implemented in an ASP.NET MVC application. I want the CSP violation report to be sent to the desired endpoint.

After reviewing CSP documentation, there are two ways to implement this:

1. [report-uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri)
2. [report-to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-to)

According to mdn doc, `report-uri` is deprecated and recommended way is the `report-to`. Just for testing purposes, I am trying to implement both.

Implementation using `report-uri` works fine without any issues - however, implementation using `report-to` doesn't work and this is where I need help to resolve the issue. Note that I am testing on Chrome browser.

Please see my code for each implementation followed by my endpoint.

This code here is the implementation using `report-uri`, and it works fine as my endpoint is made which I confirmed by putting a breakpoint:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var cspHeader = context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"].ToString();
    // Add the report-uri directive to the existing CSP header
     cspHeader += "; report-uri https://localhost:6001/ApplicationLogs/CSPReport";
    // Set the modified CSP header
    context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = cspHeader;
    await next();
});
```

This second piece of code is the implementation using the `report-to` directive, which doesn't work, as my endpoint is never reached. Please look at the code below on how I have implemented this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var reportToValue = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            group = "csp-endpoint",
            max_age = 10886400,
            endpoints = new[] { new { url = "https://localhost:6001/ApplicationLogs/CSPReport" } },
            include_subdomains = true
        }
    };

    var reportToHeader = JsonSerializer.Serialize(reportToValue);
    context.Response.Headers["Report-To"] = reportToHeader;

    // Get the existing CSP header
    var cspHeader = context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"].ToString();

    // Add the report-to directive to the existing CSP header
    cspHeader += "; report-to csp-endpoint";

    // Set the modified CSP header
    context.Response.Headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = cspHeader;

    await next();
});
```

My endpoint is:

```
endpoints.MapPost("/ApplicationLogs/CSPReport/", async context =>
{
    using var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body);
    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

    // Log the CSP report
    // This is a simple example, you might want to use a proper logging solution in a real application
    Console.WriteLine(body);
});
```

Can someone clarify what might be wrong with my `report-to` implementation?

Comment: Is the endpoint encrypted (it must be)? I see that it is configured with https, are there any certificate warnings on it? Also, localhost may not be considered trustworthy by some browsers.

Comment: @HalvorSakshaug however, the endpoint works fine when using the report-uri directive. If there was any browser issue then I believe report-uri would have not worked as well.

Comment: Also, I have tried on both Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge but same issue

Comment: Report-uri can be used with http and localhost without problems, it doesn't have the same restrictions. Chrome and Edge are both Chromium based, so they are likely similar, see if Firefox or Safari functions differently.

Comment: According to MDN docs report-to is not yet supported on Firefox. I can't test on Safari either as I have a windows machine.